# Containing algorithm for cartesian surface items

Tags: algorithm

Is there any algorithm that would help to optimally find the minimum number of rectangles to contain a certain number of items spread all over a Cartesian surface (each item is a point with x & y coordinates)? The rectangles must be orthogonal to and have the bottom segment on the Ox axis and the area of each rectangle must be < than a given value M.

Comment: This would be better off being asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ which is more about algorithms etc whereas stack is more about code you're working with...

Comment: I think that you can only look for a surface area minimising covering for *a given number of rectangles* - otherwise you'd just choose `n` zero area rectangles for `n` points...

Comment: How many points are we talking about - it is acceptable to use a brute-force solution, or do you really want a sophisticated algorithm? Are the rectangles allowed to intersect?

Comment: Also, because you say "orthogonal to and have the bottom segment on the Ox axis", it sounds like you want to approximate a point cloud with a bar chart...?

Comment: The number of points N <= 200000 and M is the maximum area a rectangle can have and it is given. I cannot take n zero area rectangles because this is the most important constraint for the output of the problem - as few rectangles as possible, and then their total area to be minimum. I also cannot use brute force as the assignment is for Algorithm Design and Complexity course and small complexity is a must. I thought about modifying the Knapsack problem for my purpose but I could not make all the connections and then I thought maybe there is another algorithm that fits better the problem...

Comment: It is easy to prove that the number of rectangles is inversely proportional to the surface of the rectangles. Minimizing both values is impossible. May be it's more about minimizing the ratio or am I missing something.

Comment: Icfseth, you are right. It is not about the areas of the rectangles - it was a mistake of mine. The only constraint about the areas of the rectangles is that each must be < that a given value M. Applying this constraint, the problem is of finding the minimum number of such rectangles such that all given points are enclosed.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but a simplification of the problem:
Assume that all points P are in general position and are sorted on x-coordinate.

The solution is then formed by finding F vertical fences (of the form `x >= fx`) that 
partition P into disjoint sets.

Each set can then be covered by an axis-aligned rectangle, where the first and last points in the set determine the width of the rectangle, and the point in the set with the highest y-coordinate determines the height, hereby determining the surface size of the rectangle.

Obviously, the trick is now to choose the fences in such a way that the number of fences (and hereby the number of rectangles) is minimized, while keeping the total surface size of all rectangles under the allowed maximum.

**Edit**
<strike>Possibly the problem of placing the F fences *can* be solved using dynamic programming.</strike> 
This is what I've come up with so far:

If so, there are at most |P|-1 fence locations; these will probably become the columns in the dynamic programming table. Each row in the dynamic programming table should represent using an additional fence (remember, we're trying to find the result with the least number of fences). Each cell (X, Y), then, would represent the optimal solution (in terms of total rectangle size) of distributing exactly Y fences over the first X available positions. However, I'm having a bit of a problem seeing how (or if) the neighbouring cells of the table can help in determining the value of a particular cell.

**Edit 2**: Forget that, I don't think a dynamic programming approach is possible. This is because I believe it's not possible to construct an optimal solution incrementally (the optimal solution configuration may change completely by adding another point or fence). This would also rule out a greedy approach.

The only think I can think of, although a little less spectactular from an algorithmic point of view, is a randomized approach such as [Simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) for distributing the fences. It doesn't guarantee *the* optimal solution, but you should be able to get pretty close to it.

**Edit 3**: In response to the reaction under this post, how about we don't necessarily require the *best* solution, but go for a 'pretty good' solution instead, and apply what you're learning right now.

In any case, you'll probably need to sort all points from left to right.

A greedy solution could be to define the first rectangle so that it includes the leftmost point. Next, expand the rectangle so that it includes the point to the right of it. Keep adding the next point until the rectangle would exceed its maximum size. In that case, start with a new rectangle and start adding points again, etc.

A divide and conquer way of obtaining a solution could be to start with the rectangle that covers all the points. Obviously, this rectangle exceeds the maximum size M, so you split it vertically into 2 smaller rectangles Ml and Mr, according to some heuristic (exactly down the middle, or at the point where two subsequent points are furthest apart, for example). Recursively process Ml and Mr in the same way, either splitting the rectangles again or reporting the found rectangle as part of the result if it is <= M.

Note that for both approaches, the results could be arbitrarily bad for some contrived configurations, but in general the solutions should be 'ok'.

Comment: You lost me with all these programming methods. If it helps, dynammic programming and the Greedy method were two of the chapters of the course the assignment is for. I am currently trying to use about Divide et Impera and recursivity but no result yet...

Comment: @binar: No problem :) I've added some new suggestions.

Comment: I have already considered these two approaches on the paper. I guess I'll stick with one of them or start reading all the courses of the professor... Thanks a lot, Astrotrain.